# Xcode build target difference - arm64 and armv7, arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, arm

I had created 2 new projects on Xcode this week for 2 different apps. For some reason one of the project always fails compiling for the device target. I then realized that the device target is different for both the project. For the working project "Any iOS Project (arm64)" The project which fails to build has "Any iOS Project (armv7, arm64)"

What causes the device target to change this way and what is the difference?

Answer (score 15):

`armv7` is 32bit architecture that was supported by earlier iOS versions [up till 10.3.4](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS). `arm64` is 64bit architecture which is supported by [newer devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html).

If your project has minimum iOS version which is below iOS 11.0, Xcode will automatically pick both `armv7` and `arm64`.

In case if Xcode does not pick the required architecture automatically, it can be added in build settings as shown below:

[image: iOS target device architecture editing in Xcode build settings]

Comment: Thanks for this useful information. for which device we are using armv7s

Comment: @Chandni https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A6, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A6X